# How do I dynamically resolve message attribute value with Spring Validator JSR 303?

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using Spring Validator (JSR 303)  with annotation and would like to resolve the attribute (idEnveloppe) value in an error message. Consider this simple scenario:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "GCE-COT-DTC-RJFLX03 La donnée &idEnveloppe du bloc entête du flux de cotisation DSN n'est pas renseignée")
@NotNull(message = "GCE-COT-DTC-RJFLX03 La donnée &idEnveloppe du bloc entête du flux de cotisation DSN n'est pas renseignée")
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{14}", message = "GCE-COT-DTC-RJFLX04 La donnée '${idEnveloppe}' du bloc entête du flux de cotisation DSN n'est pas valide}")
private String idEnveloppe;
```

print error:

```
private BindingResult bindAndValidate(final DsnCotFluxDto item) {

    DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(item);
    binder.setValidator(validator);
    binder.validate();
    // LOG.error(binder.getErrors().getBindingResult().toString());

    return binder.getBindingResult();

}

/**
 * Etude du cas des erreurs
 * @param results résultat des validations
 * @param item
 * @throws BusinessException
 */
private void buildValidationException(final BindingResult results, final DsnCotFluxDto item) throws BusinessException {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    String code;
    String message;
    String rejectedValue;


    for (ObjectError error : results.getAllErrors()) {

        code = error.getDefaultMessage().substring(0, 19);
        message = error.getDefaultMessage().substring(20);
        // rejectedValue = error.getObjectName().getRejectedValue();

        msg.append("\n\t  \t---Error code : -- " + code + " ---Error message : --" + message + "\n");
        LOG.warn("\n\t  \t---Error code : -- " + code + " ---Error message : --" + message + "\n");
    }

    // throw new ValidationException(msg.toString());
}
```

Thank you

Comment: i have do it with this rejectedValue = error.toString().substring(error.toString().indexOf("rejected") + 16, error.toString().indexOf("; codes") - 1) + " "; but it is not clean code

Answer (score 3):

Here is the quote from [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-interpolation-with-message-expressions):

> As of Hibernate Validator 5 (Bean Validation 1.1) it is possible to use the Unified Expression Language (as defined by JSR 341) in constraint violation messages. [...] The validation engine makes the following objects available in the EL context:
>
> - the currently validated value (property, bean, method parameter etc.) under the name validatedValue

So, try the following:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{14}", message = "GCE-COT-DTC-RJFLX04 La donnée '${validatedValue}' du bloc entête du flux de cotisation DSN n'est pas valide}")
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but that not work, it work with this too rejectedValue = ((FieldError) error).getRejectedValue().toString();

Comment: Is it possible that you're using old Hibernate version?

Comment: <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1.CR1</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: That version is very, very old. I recommend you upgrade to Hibernate Validator 5 (5.4.1.Final is the latest stable version).

Comment: The problem that i can't change the project configuration

Answer (score 0):

i get them with this

```
 rejectedValue = ((FieldError) error).getRejectedValue().toString();
```

After i insert them in the message string like:

```
  message = new StringBuilder(message).insert(10, rejectedValue).toString();
```

and it work fine

Thank you